# Getting Xcode 5 variable inspector to show custom summary and/or synthetic children

Tags: xcode, lldb

I have some C++ classes from a library which have opaque data types. Xcode doesn't understand them and so can't show them in the variable inspector. I've written Python scripts for lldb which can decompose these opaque types correctly and return synthetic children. I have a Python class OpaqVector_syntheticChildren which implements get_child_at_index(), num_children() and so on.

For example, at the lldb prompt when the program is paused at a breakpoint in Xcode:
    (lldb) frame variable sarr
    (OpaqueVector) sarr = {
      [0] = 1
      [1] = 2
      [2] = 3
    }

However, in the variable inspector, sarr shows the pink 'S' to show it's a structure and has no summary nor expansion arrow. I can right-click and choose 'Print description of "sarr"' and get the correct (matching above) output in the lldb console. Is there some extra trick to get Xcode itself show the structure's synthetic children?

Comment: What happens if you do frame variable -d run -- sarr? Except for a very weird bug, which I would encourage you to report on bugreport.apple.com for good measure, the only thing I can think of right now is dynamic types kicking in and confusing the type matching algorithm in the UI.

Comment: Your command worked correctly, but I just found the actual problem and it was in my Python code. My class' has_children() method was not returning True when it should have - chalk it up to inexperience with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode calls the has_children() method of the class you provide to generate the synthetic children. If that function does not return True, it won't call num_children() or get_child_at_index(), whereas the lldb command prompt doesn't seem to do that check. Hence, if you have a bug in that function you'll get the behaviour I described in the question.

Comment: It looks like the lldb prompt will call get_child_at_index for indexes (0..255) regardless of what num_children and has_children return. You have to return None for all indexes >= self.num_children. Currently waiting for Xcode to finish printing 256*256*256 log lines :-(